# jQuery performance bad on iPad

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

I have some problems with the performance of this. On the computer it works just fine, but it's for an iPad presentation and the page is loading really slow and on click the object doesnt fade out and after some time the next object just appears and the button is active. Anyone can tell me how this comes? That the iPad is lagging and the Computer is not?

```
$('body').click(function(e){
                    var evt = e ? e:window.event;
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    var Elem = e.target;
                    if(Elem.id == 'front'){
                        if($('#dc70-1').css('display')=='none'){
                            $('img:visible').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                                $('#dc70-1').fadeIn('slow');
                            });
                            $('button.active').removeClass('active');
                            $('#front').addClass('active');
                        }
                    }

                    else if(Elem.id == 'extended'){
                        if($('#dc70-2').css('display')=='none'){
                        $('img:visible').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                            $('#dc70-2').fadeIn('slow');
                        });

                        $('button.active').removeClass('active');
                        $('#extended').addClass('active');
                        }
                    }

                    else if(Elem.id == 'right'){
                        if($('#dc70-3').css('display')=='none'){
                        $('img:visible').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                            $('#dc70-3').fadeIn('slow');
                        });

                        $('button.active').removeClass('active');
                        $('#right').addClass('active');
                        }
                    }

                    else if(Elem.id == 'left'){
                        if($('#dc70-4').css('display')=='none'){
                        $('img:visible').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                            $('#dc70-4').fadeIn('slow');
                        });

                        $('button.active').removeClass('active');
                        $('#left').addClass('active');
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Edit: The problem was the following: I had a $(windows).on('resize', function()) trigger as the wrap. Because in another document I had to use this, because the jquery variables were loading before the content was loading. So then I forgot to put the resize trigger out(because I'm using the click event now) and after I put it away, then it worked. So never double wrap your triggers :D

Comment: How old is the iPad and what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery version: jquery-1.10.2.min and the iPad is an iPad 4

Comment: It sounds like the iPad is struggling with the fade animations. If you run a bare-bones element fade in JsFiddle then do you get the same results?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand that question? I run the application via xampp on my computer and there I don't have any problems

Comment: JQuery is a Javascript library, and Javascript is a client-side language,  so it does not matter what server you use. JQuery fadeIn and fadeOut are very CPU intensive so the iPad cannot handle it

Comment: Ahhhh now I get it. I've been reading about this sometime. So it would be better to handle it via add/removeClass and use CSS3 animate, right?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you use the $() operator to traverse the DOM, jQuery takes some time to parse and navigate the document.  When you have many of these calls stacked up in a method call, as you do, they will slow down operations.

You can cache the results of a jQuery traversal with some syntax like this:

```
var $left = $("#left");
```

In further use of the #left element, use the $left variable instead.  I prefer to name variables that point to jQuery objects with the $ prefix so that I know its a jQuery object.

Try using native search and manipulation commands.  This will also reduce the overhead of going through the jQuery abstraction. For example, instead of:

```
$("#left").addClass("active")
```

try

```
document.getElementById("left").classList.add('active');
```

Comment: curiosity question: if it's such a big difference in efficiency, why doesn't the jQuery `$()` operator translate to the appropriate native Javascript search function?

Comment: It does a search across browser capabilities to determine the most efficient way to navigate the DOM.  If you can cache the results of one of these searches, it will help immensely.  Updating answer to demonstrate cache technique.

Comment: Although your answer is true in terms of performance, it does nothing to answer the question at hand.

Comment: .. and the question was changed after I submitted my answer.